# option to bind html5 video tag source value from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have retrieved the value for the video source tag in javascript and now am trying to bind the javascript function to the video tag .

```
<asp:HiddenField ID ="lbl1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value="http://test/test1/dilse.mp4#t=00,20"></asp:HiddenField>

 <video id="myvideo" onload="sourceval();" controls></video>
```

Javascript:

```
function sourceval() {
var src1 = window.document.getElementById('lbl1').value;
myvideo.src = src1;
alert(src1);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing exactly? Do you have errors? Is something working differently than you expected? Where are you caling the `sourceval()` function?

Comment: initially i was using c# code to bind the value with attributes.src and now am clueless as how do i bind the function in video as i tried using onloadevent ="sourceval()" but it doesnt work.any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got fixed up by adding the listener in load function

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
         sourceval();
     });
```

Comment: Great that you were able to find the solution yourself. Now you can mark your own answer as correct to show others clearly that the problem is solved.